# Zend Framework 2 and Date picker

Tags: php, jquery, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-framework2

I am using zend framework 2 and creating a form by extending Form .. For a date field how to use data picker using Form

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with using HTML5 then you could use date form element from [Zend\Form\Element](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.elements.html#date)